# Play framework 2.2: How to get current controller and action in java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

In my application authentication scheme is based on user and role. users with particular role have access to particular action method.

To implement this I have done following

1.Write custom action

```
public class Authorization extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    public Promise<Result> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        //check access
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

2.Annotate controller with action

```
@With(actions.Authorization.class)
public class Upload extends Controller {
    ....
}
```

In my action I have access to user which is in session. I want to get current controller and action so that I can authenticate user. Is there any way to this?

I have read about creating custom annotation with params and in each controller pass parameters to identify the action. But it seems to much work and error prone if by mistake i write wrong action name while copy paste.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a reference to a controller object or just an identifier (i.e. String) of which controller underlies the action?

Comment: Both will work. I was looking for controller and method, String and object both are ok.

Comment: Then are you going to have a big `if...else` structure in your `Authorization` class ? You really should define at controller or method level the role(s) required to execute the method and check it in your `Authorization` class. It will be really less error prone.

Comment: Thanks it was indeed error prone. So I have created custom annotation for each type of access an put it in each controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `context.request().path()` to get a string with the path used. This will not include any query parameters, so if you want them you can use `getQueryParameter` or `uri` (full url) methods of the same object.

If you need more information than this you can use `context.args`. This will give you a map with the following keys (in Play 2.2 atleast):

```
ROUTE_VERB          -> The HTTP verb used (ex: GET)
ROUTE_ACTION_METHOD -> The method called (ex: getUserFavorites)
ROUTE_CONTROLLER    -> Controller class (ex: controllers.api.UsersController)
ROUTE_COMMENTS      -> ???
ROUTE_PATTERN       -> THE URL used (ex: users/favorites)
```

Comment: Thanks! ROUTE_CONTROLLER and ROUTE_ACTION_METHOD gave the desired result.