# How to get current controller instance in Play Framework (with Java)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need update some properties of the current controller instance dynamically, for this reason I need get the controller object related with the current request to check if it is necessary update the values of some of its properties.

I have been searching on internet some similar questions and I found this answer:

[Play 2: How to get current controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646335/play-framework-2-2-how-to-get-current-controller-and-action-in-java)

However in my case, I do not only need the name of the controller class, but the object instance as well.

On the other hand, I know that is possible to override the following function: **GlobalSettings.getControllerInstance** but I don't need to manage the creation of controller instances I only need to access to the current instance, besides this function was removed on Play 2.4.

Comment: It is not recommended to keep a state in your controller, this has many cons, like different data between machines, thread safety, etc.. If you need to keep a state, why not keep it in a different class as Atomic reference or something? make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't want to "keep a state" in controllers. I had developed a dependency injection functionality that works fine in Play 2 and I would like adapt it to the version 2.4